# Set pug includes to not compile

Tags: directory, pug-loader

I am running the pug CLI with

> pug src --out web --watch

If I have

```
src/
   index.pug 
   includes/
      scripts.pug
web/
  index.html (generated)
```

And in index.pug: `include includes/scripts.pug`

With this setup if I modify the scripts.pug, it generates web/includes/scripts.html that I don't need and I don't want in order to keep things clean.

Is there a way to avoit certain files / directories to compile?
(for now a workaround is having the includes in html form but maybe there's a way)

Answer (score 1):

Adding an underscore prefix to files should tell Pug to not compile them directly. This is super helpful for files that are only used as includes.

So you should rename `scripts.pug` to `_scripts.pug`:

```
src/
  index.pug 
  includes/
    _scripts.pug
web/
  index.html (generated)
```

And then rewrite your `include` statement in `index.pug` to be: `include includes/_scripts.pug`

Comment: are you sure? I accepted the answer but didn't test until now and it seems to not work. By what I am seeing there's a specific pug-cli2 that must be installed.

Comment: It works for the `gulp-pug` package but it may be different for other tools.

Answer (score 1):

The pug-cli doesn't know about not compiling certain files. Like the previous answer mentions, it does work with gulp-pug but not pug-cli. The only way I can think of not to compile includes or extends files is to put those files in a separate root directory. For example:

```
src/
  templates/
        views/
            index.pug
        includes/
            scripts.pug
web/
  index.html (generated)
```

Then set pug to compile the views directory only.

```
pug -w src/templates/views/ -o web/ -P
```